# r, caret - preprocessing range vs scale

Tags: r, caret, data-preprocessing

I noticed that caret preprocessing has a range method to "scale predictors between 0,1". When does this option become more desirable than center and scaling?

Answer (score 1):

Not to me since there might be occasions where predictors occur with values outside of the range seen in the data.